# Accessing lists using sharepoint mobile apps will not respect the setting we defined on the lists. any advice how to fix this

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, mobile

I am facing this sever problem which i were not aware of inside our sharepoint online site collection/s. Where on some sharepoint online site collections, i have added some custom lists. And inside the custom lists' New and Edit list forms i have added some scripts (using the script editor web part), the script will hide/show some fields based on other fields; values. and everything was working well. here is part of the script inside the list Edit form:-

```
<script src="/Resources/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>$(function() {
  $("input[id^='ProjectEstimated_']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $("img[id^='ProjectEstimated_']").hide();
  $("input[id^='ProjectEstimatedCompletion_']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $("img[id^='ProjectEstimatedCompletion_']").hide();;

//code goes here
```

Today i download the sharepoint mobile app on my iPhone >> i access the sites using the SP app, but i have noted these problems:-

1- the above custom script will not have any effect, so now when editing an item inside SP mobile app >> all the fields will be shown.

2- I have a managed metadata field >> and this field will be shown as read-only inside SP mobile app.

3- Using PnP i have defined to hide some fields inside the New and Edit forms, as follow:-

```
$fieldTitle = "SiteCreated"
$customfield = $Context.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($fieldTitle)
$customfield.SetShowInEditForm($true)
$customfield.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$customfield.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
```

but those settings will not have any effect, and all the fields will be shown on SP mobile app !!!

4- i have disabled attaching files inside the custom list settings>> but when add/edit items inside SP mobile app users can attach files to the items..

So can anyone adivce how i can have a short term fix, by either:-

1- prevent accessing some site collection (prefereed some lists and libraries) on mobile apps?

2- prevent add or edit items and document on mobile apps, and only allow users to view the items and documents?

any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, SharePoint Mobile app has a mind of its own with a lot of limitations. For example, it will still show OOTB item forms even when you replaced them with PowerApps. One potential fix would be to write SPFx Header extension that injects a script. This approach works on SharePoint Mobile, but the problem is that Extensions won't run on the New/Edit forms. So this approach won't work for you.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov i am not sure how Microsoft did not take these points into account.. and will simply show all fields inside the create and edit forms...

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov if Microsoft provide something to help us, but they know that it can cause issues as the ones i am facing, then it should allow us to prevent accessing these lists from the mobile app. For example when MS introduce the modern UI, they know that some list forms already have scripts added to them, so they allow us to prevent certain lists from been rendered inside the modern UI. even on MSDN, a lot of replies from moderators mentioned to use classic UI,when users ask on how to do some customization to the list forms.. the appraoch MS is approaching the mobile app is unacceptable.

Comment: they can not force us to us something we do not want our users to use!!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can accomplish #2 with an Intune conditional access policy, but it will affect ALL site collections in the tenant and requires an additional license for each user.  I do not think that #1 is possible.

Comment: to be honest i do not know how Microsoft handle things and it does not even think how developers need to handle all these inconstancy.. now on MS official documentation they mention that you can define to hide a site column in Edit list form using PnP, then we realize that sharepoint mobile app will ignore these settings... From a professional point of view this count as a bug that should be fixed... the idea is not with having SP mobile app out of the box, the idea is to access the sites in consistent way...